# Checking Condition for Independence of Random Variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, random-variable, independence

Which of the following conditions imply independence of the random variables X and Y?

A.  P(X >a I Y >a) = P (X> a) for all a in **R**.

B.  P(X >a I Y < b)  = P (X > a) for all a, b in **R**.

C.   X and Y are uncorrelated.

I think  that answer to this question is both option A and B but the given answer is only option B. Can anybody explain the reason why only B is correct and not A?

Comment: Hint: there are two differences between (A) and (B).  One is trivial (a reversal of the inequality).  The other matters.

Comment: You need the self study tag. Uncorrelated is misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, B says that events related to $Y$ are irrelevant of events related to $X$ because we can choose $a$ and $b$ freely. In (a), these events have dependence, i.e. $a=b$. So, the spectrum of conditions for independence is underrepresented.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!